# How to simulate lag on a local kafka replica?

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, local

I'm doing some "chaos" engineering and have kafka running with 3 brokers locally.
I'm reading from a replica and would like to test what happens when the replica leaves the ISR.

Is there any way to "force" this to happen? Since everything is local I can't "turn off the wifi" or do anything like that.

Comment: Hope it helps: https://www.gremlin.com/community/tutorials/the-first-4-chaos-experiments-to-run-on-apache-kafka/

Comment: thanks @zforgo I saw this page as well but was looking for something free :)

Comment: why don't you just killing the process for one of the brokers?, how do you set your `advertised.listeners`?

Comment: killing the broker is one test that I do, but I also really wanted to test for the broker to be out of the ISR. Killing the broker is a lot different (connection won't work, when in the ISR the connection should still work) @KarimTawfik

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trickle](https://github.com/mariusae/trickle) to limit the bandwidth for one of your broker.

```
trickle -s -d [download rate in KB/s] -u [upload rate in KB/s] <process of your broker>
```

trickle does it based on the process, I haven't test it but perhaps best to call it where your kafka broker launches the jvm such as in `kafka-run-class.sh`

```
# Which java to use
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="trickle -s -d 10 -u 5 java"
else
  JAVA="trickle -s -d 10 -u 5 $JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
```

https://www.tecmint.com/limit-linux-network-bandwidth-usage-with-trickle/

Comment: How exactly does this command work? How does it know what TCP server to watch?

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, I just updated it, it's acting as a proxy with the executable process.